# converting datetime field to date in sql query in laravel contorller

Tags: php, sql, laravel

i have to execute an sql query into laravel controller the query inclueds where caluse in which it compares a field from database which is in datetime type with another field that i get from the blade which has a date type, so i have to convert the database field from datetime type to date type

this is my query in laravel controller, i have tried dateformat but id doesnt work

```
 $querydate = $request->get('querydate');
 $data = DB::table('logs')

        ->select('logs.user_id','logs.NUMCCP','logs.created_at') 

           ->where  (DB::raw('(DATE_FORMAT(logs.created_at,"%Y-%m-%d"))'),$querydate)
           ->orderby('logs.created_at','desc') 
        ->get();
```

**$querydate** is in **yyyy-mm-dd** format,
**logs.created_at** is in datetime type and **$querydate** is in date type 
so i'm trying frist to convert **logs.created_at** into a date type after that i wanna get the information when **logs.created_at** equals to **$querydate**

i have tried several syntaxes i found on the net  but they didnt work for example:
`->whereRaw("DATE_FORMAT(logs.created_at, '%Y-%m-%d') = $querydate")`
`->where(DB::raw("(DATE_FORMAT(logs.created_at,'%Y-%m-%d'))"),$querydate)`
`->orWhere('CAST(logs.created_at AS DATE)', '=', $querydate)`
none of these is working

Comment: And is `$querydate` also in `yyyy-mm-dd` format?

Comment: You can simplify it to `DATE(logs.created_at)` instead of using `DATE_FORMAT`.

Comment: yes ```  $querydate``` is in ```yyyy-mm-dd  ``` format

Comment: What about the query isn't working? Is it giving an error or just not returning any data?

Comment: i had tried a static data instead of query somthing like this ``` ->where  (DB::raw('(DATE_FORMAT(logs.created_at,"%Y-%m-%d"))'),'2018-02-18')```

Comment: i've tried `DATE(logs.created_at)` instead of `DATE_FORMAT` it doesn't work neither

Comment: Again, what about the query isn't working? No data, or is it giving an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `logs.created` must be timestamp and laravel has several ways to select and filter by given date.

1. `$query->whereDate('logs.created_at', '2020-01-25')`
2. `$query->whereRaw('DATE(logs.created_at) = ?', ['2020-01-25'])`
3. `$query->where(DB::raw('DATE(logs.created_at)'), '2020-01-25')`

mysql `DATE` function converts date from given timestamp (or string) with default format `Y-m-d` or `yyyy-mm-dd`

Hope this helps you

Comment: thanks so mutch, it did work finally i've tried `$query->whereDate('logs.created_at', '2020-01-25')` it works even if **created_at** is not a timestamp type it a datetime i'm sure of it

Comment: I am glad to help you, @Hadjer, Please consider to upvote and accept answer if it helped you.

Comment: sure @Malkhazi with big pleasure, thanks again i was straggeld with it since a while

Answer (score 0):

In Eloquent you can use whereDate method:

```
$q->whereDate('created_at', '=', $querydate);
```

You might need convert `$querydate` to proper format: `$querydate->format('Y-m-d');` 
Also you should do queries from Model not from Controller as it contradicts MVC pattern!